# Video tag zoom on mobile Chrome (Android)

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, zooming

I'm using a WebRTC stream as a source for a video tag that I want to play on a mobile device (Nexus 5X + Chrome).

Completely random, the video stream on the phone zooms in to the top-left 25% of the actual video. The video controls do not change when the zooming happens and after a few seconds everything goes back to normal.

**It never occurs on desktop browsers and the Chrome console for the phone does not output any error.**

HTML:

```
<div class="video-player-container ratio-16by9">
    <video class="video" autoplay height="100%" width="100%" id="video-player">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video></div>
```

SCSS:

```
.video-player-container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: $color-primary;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.ratio-16by9 {
    @include aspect-ratio(16, 9);
}

@mixin aspect-ratio($width, $height) {
    position: relative;

    &:before {
        display: block;
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: ($height / $width) * 100%;
    }

    .content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed with Facebook (mobile web) videos. It's been almost a month now. Samsung S10, Chrome beta.